# Loading companion objects in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I use :load in the spark-shell it appears as though lines are read separately and thus companion objects are not read in the same "source" file. :paste does not appear to take arguments.

Previously I was building and loading a jar with my code into the spark-shell but was hoping to run it as a script for simplicity. Does anyone have a favorite workaround?

Answer (score 3):

A sufficiently recent [shell](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.1/repl/scala-2.11/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/repl/SparkILoop.scala#L707) will have :paste file.

Or, as a workaround, link the templates this way to :load them:

```
class C(i: Int) {
  def c = { println("C..."); i }
}; object C {
  def apply(i: Int = 42) = new C(i)
}
```

Or,

```
scala> (new $intp.global.Run) compile List("C.scala")

scala> new C().c
C...
res1: Int = 42
```

More API:

```
scala> import reflect.io._
import reflect.io._

scala> import reflect.internal.util._
import reflect.internal.util._

scala> val code = File("C.scala").slurp
code: String =
"
class C(i: Int) { def c = { println("C..."); i } }
object C { def apply(i: Int = 42) = new C(i) }
"

scala> $intp interpret code
defined class C
defined object C
res0: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IR.Result = Success

scala> C()
res1: C = C@f2f2cc1
```

Similarly,

```
scala> $intp interpret s"object X { $code }"
defined object X
res0: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IR.Result = Success

scala> X.C()
res1: X.C = X$C@7d322cad
```

My startup script defines:

```
implicit class `interpreter interpolator`(val sc: StringContext) { def i(args: Any*) = $intp interpret sc.s(args: _*) }
```

for

```
scala> i"val x = 42"
x: Int = 42
res0: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IR.Result = Success
```

Answer (score 0):

This `compile` trick doesn't appear to work with "script" files. It expects a source file compilable by `scalac`, where all `val` and `def` declarations are inside a type.

So, an alternative hack that will work with `:load` is to write the case class and companion object inside another object. Here I just pasted the code, without using `:paste`, but it works with `:load`, too.

```
scala> object O {
     |   case class C(s: String)
     |   object C {
     |     def apply() = new C("<no string>")
     |   }
     | }
defined module O

scala> O.C()
res0: O.C = C(<no string>)
```

Comment: Scripts also allow repl commands; my init.script mixes `:paste file` with imports and other definitions.